# Can PKCS#12 files contain multiple certificate chains?

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, openssl, pkcs12

I know that PKCS#12 files can contain multiple certificates and private keys.
However, I could not find any resource where any limit was mentioned for the number of certificate chains or private keys that could be contained.
Is there a max limit of certificate chains that can be present in a PKCS#12 file?

I assumed that a max of 1 certificate chain can be created per PKCS#12 file and thus, there can only be 1 private key. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: Since you tagged openssl, note the _commandline program_ `openssl pkcs12 -export ...` will only create a file with one privatekey and its (leaf) cert, plus any other cert or certs you want regardless of whether it or each of them is part of the leaf cert's chain(s), and need not consist of or contain the complete chain (but _other_ programs _using_ this file may want the complete chain); _or_ with `-nokeys` a file with _no_ privatekey and only cert(s) regardless of chaining. A custom program using the _library_ is different.

Answer (score 1):

PKCS#12 container may contain multiple encrypted private keys and public certificates. The upper limit is not strictly defined.

Comment: However, is there some limit for the number of certificate chains that can be contained?

Comment: No, there is no such limit I'm aware of.

Comment: @KumaravelRajan A certificate chain isn't really a "thing". A PKCS#12 file could for example contain one private key and three certificates. It doesn't matter that one certificate just happens to sign another. However, if you aim to store 30000 certificates and 15000 private keys in one file, you may be doing something wrong.